# Establishing equality between two integrals

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and also suppose $n \ge 3$ and $\lambda > 0$. Define $u(x):=(1+|x|^2)^{\frac{2-n}2}$ and $u_\lambda(x):=(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+|x|^2})^{\frac{n-2}2}$. How can I show that $$\|u_{\lambda}\|_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|u\|_{L^{2^*}({\mathbb{R}^n})}$$ with $2^*:=\frac{2n}{n-2}$?

My work on this:

It would suffice to prove that $\|u_{\lambda}\|_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{2^*}=\|u\|_{L^{2^*}({\mathbb{R}^n})}^{2^*}$.

I have
\begin{align}
\|u_{\lambda}\|_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{2^*}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left|\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+|x|^2} \right)^{\frac{n-2}2} \right|^{\frac{2n}{n-2}} \, dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\lambda^n}{\left(\lambda^2+|x|^2\right)^n} \, dx
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{2^*}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left|\left(1+|x|^2\right)^{\frac{2-n}2} \right|^{\frac{2n}{n-2}} \, dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(1+|x|^2\right)^n} \, dx.
\end{align}
I am left to establish the equality of these two integrals, that is, show $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\lambda^n}{\left(\lambda^2+|x|^2\right)^n} \, dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(1+|x|^2\right)^n} \, dx.$$ Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^n x \frac{\lambda^n}{(\lambda^2+|x|^2)^n} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^n x \frac1{\lambda^n} \frac1{\displaystyle\left (1+\frac{|x|^2}{\lambda^2} \right )^n} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^n y \frac1{(1+|y|^2)^n}$$